# ¿Qué archivos debo respaldar si deseo seguir actualizando apps en play store realizadas con flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console

## Publicando mi primera app realizada con Flutter

Actualmente publique una app realizada con **Flutter** en **Google play**
para lo cual seguí las instrucciones de la [documentación](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) para generar el apk release ejecutando `flutter build apk`

Pero **Google play** no me acepto el apk por lo que genere un **app bundle** con `flutter build appbundle`.

## Publicando mi segunda app realizada con Flutter

Realice todos los pasos anteriores, solo que ahora si genere un **app bundle** desde un inicio, pero resulta que después de subir el archivo revise que tenia un error en el titulo lo corregí, de paso **copie el archivo key.jks que genere para tenerlo como respaldo**,

Al ejecutar `flutter build appbundle` me manda un error de que el archivo **key.jks** había sido manipulado o la contraseña incorrecta, lo cual no pudo ser, por que no cambie la contraseña ni moví nada relacionado con la key.

genere un nuevo archivo **key.jks** con los mismos datos ejecute de nuevo `flutter build appbundle` se genero todo sin problemas.

**Intento subir el nuevo archivo y manda el siguiente mensaje**

> **No se ha podido subir el archivo**
>
> Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con la clave incorrecta. Asegúrate
>   de que esté firmado con la clave de firma correcta e inténtalo de
>   nuevo: SHA1:

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/303182/76401) la publicación que genere para ver este problema ya que no le pude dar una solución

Por suerte la aplicación no la puse en revisión por lo que pude borrar el proyecto en **Google play** y generar nuevamente la ficha de play store y todo lo demás y me acepto sin problemas el **app appbundle** que genere.

**Entonces me queda la duda que archivos debo respaldar o que datos son los que debo tener respaldados para en un futuro poder seguir actualizando mis apps aun cuando cambie de maquina o formatee la misma.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los datos que debes de respaldar solo es la key o la llave con que firmas tu app, ya que ese es el identificador que tendrá tu app dentro de Google play, cuando hagas una actualización de tu app, ese apk debe de estar firmado por la misma key que subiste a Google play.

Comment: Cuando hice eso de intentar respaldar la **key**, fue cuando me marco el error de que el archivo fue manipulado y no me dejo firmar el **apk** o el **app undle** por lo tanto como respaldo esa **key**?